# pg_dump unable to produce a valid backup

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a table in postgis as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE public.a_meter (
    smid integer NOT NULL,
    smgeometry public.geometry(Point,32640) NOT NULL,
    install_node_code text,
    "ID" text,
    proj_id text,
    voltage_level public.voltage_level_enum2,
    design_status public.mv_pole_des,
    serial text,
    feeder_name text,
    specific_id text,
    sequence_num smallint,
    amp_ratio text,
    man_year integer,
    ins_year integer,
    mspec_no text,
    description text,
    angle smallint DEFAULT 0,
    dist_name public.dist_name_enum,
    manufactor text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (public.get_manufactor(mspec_no)) STORED,
    spec_name text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (public.a_meter_spec_name(specific_id)) STORED,
    type_ad text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (public.a_meter_type_ad(specific_id)) STORED,
    maxmtr text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (public.a_meter_maxmtr(specific_id)) STORED,
    "Type" text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (public.a_meter_type(specific_id)) STORED,
    rat_cur text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (public.a_meter_rat_cur(specific_id)) STORED
);
```

As obvious, there are several generated columns in it.
I make a backup using the following script:

```
pg_dump.exe --file "C:\\Users\\rasam\\Desktop\\PG_gis.sql" --host "localhost" --port "5432" --username "postgres" --no-password --verbose --format=p --inserts --table "public.a_meter" "electricity"
```

However, the backup generated is not a valid SQL code, since the generated columns are not backed up correctly. The values are stored like a regular column as follows:

```
INSERT INTO public.a_meter VALUES (204, '0101000020807F00008FC2F528A22A204115AE47A1FFA14F41', '', 'AMP3153546', '', '', 'اجرا شده', '', 'نادر - PDS3570966 - 8', '7', NULL, '', NULL, NULL, '22', '', 180, 'بجنورد', 'BEW', 'AMP017', 'آنالوگ', 'ندارد', 'BE-96', '');
```

The strange part is that when I clone the table schema and fill it with the data, the backup is correctly produced. But, I cannot do that for all tables for all my customers.

Comment: This question is not related with postgis or any GIS technology.

Comment: same question, with some comments and no "answer", is here: [Restoring PG database from dump fails due to generated columns (stackoverflow.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64600614/restoring-pg-database-from-dump-fails-due-to-generated-columns). When I try to reproduce this (with a simple table, like in SO article), I always get "DEFAULT" in the generated columns (PostgreSQL v.15)

Comment: What version? What is the minimal amount of work needed to reproduce this?  Is the non-Latinate alphabet needed?  Are the custom types whose definition you didn't include needed?  Is the large number of generated column needed, or just one?  Can you reproduce it without the functions whose definition you didn't include here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is yours: you lied to the database by saying that a function like `public.get_manufactor(text)` is `IMMUTABLE`, when really it seems to depend on other data in the database. You can only label a function `IMMUTABLE` if it returns the same result for the same argument, *no matter what is in the database*.

The correct way to store redundant data (if you need to store them at all) is to use a regular column and to fill it with a `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger.